# CSS: Safari on Mac doesn't adhere to my Submit Button style

Tags: css, macos

I have applied the following CSS to a `FORM` submit button:

```
font:normal 15px helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
padding:6px;
```

On Windows, regardless of the browser (IE/Firefox/Chrome), this increase the FORM submit button and give the button spacing padding of 6px.

However, on OS X (Mac), the form submit button is not stylized at all. Meaning, the font size is the default and no padding is being applied.

Any idea on how I can make a FORM submit button bigger on OS X (Mac)?

Answer (score 19):

You need to add this to your CSS:

```
input {
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Safari 4, padding and sizes won't take effect on submit buttons unless you set a background or border. Example:

```
background: #ccc; /* without this, the other styles won't show up */    
font: normal 15px helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
padding: 6px;
```

Comment: If I add a background color, that doesn't make it look then like a native button

Comment: Correct. Safari does not allow you to make a native button larger than the default -- only smaller. See http://webkit.org/blog/28/buttons/ for more details.

Comment: Nope. If you want it to look native with big text, your only option is aping the native look with CSS -- e.g., a background image. Apple is protective of their look-and-feel.

Comment: Same problem happens in chrome for mac too, Justin's answer works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `<input type="submit" />` use `<button type="submit">Submit Text</button>`, if I remember correctly, this has much better support for css stylings.

Answer (score 0):

Make an image button. Safari will not style buttons, or checkboxes, or drop down menus, etc.

Comment: Safari 4 under Windows allows it.  Are they offering different functionality under OS X?

Answer (score 0):

Styling form controls is very problematic. See [this example](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/buttons/) - while other browsers apply some styles, all the buttons look nearly identical in Safari.

One solution is to use a `<div>` with the `onclick` JavaScript attribute. This way you can apply standard CSS normally. I'd recommend starting with a button then using JS to switch in the better-looking code as progressive enhancement.